# What is the full name of E. G. Gray?

Tags: neuroscience, history, synapses, literature

E. G. Gray is Neuro scientist who found and described first the two major morphologically defined synapse types (Gray Type I (asymmetric) and II (symmetric)) in his work 
[E G Gray (Oct. 1959). “Axo-somatic and axo-dendritic synapses of the cerebral cortex: an electron microscope study”. In: Journal of Anatomy 93.4, pp. 420–433](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1244535/)

However I am unable to find his full name nor further information about his life.

Comment: Is this really a biology question?

Comment: @Amory I think questions on the history of the science are pertinent to its future study, but others may not share that opinion

Comment: See http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51/should-questions-about-the-history-of-biology-be-considered-on-topic

Comment: I couldn't agree more, but I don't know that this is history so much as a question involving an historical biologist.  "Initials" aren't exactly history, but I admit I'm not sure there's a better place.

Comment: It's about his bio, isn't? * ironic smile *
I shared your doubts, but I think this question will be useful especially for people using this SE site. Though I have to admit that main reason I asked it here instead of a more general site like Yahoo answers, is that I knew the people here were most likely to answer this question correctly. And Indeed it was correctly and comprehensively answered within minutes by @jonsca. Thank You very much therefor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edward George Gray went by the first name of George, which isn't evident from his initials (he was born Edward George), but I happened to stumble upon the Wikipedia article below.  From there, I found his obituary.

From [his obituary](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/obituary-george-gray-1115676.html):

> GEORGE GRAY was a pioneer in the study of brain ultrastructure. He was Professor of Cytology in the anatomy department at University College London from 1967 to 1977 and then headed the Laboratory of Biological Ultrastructure at the National Institute for Medical Research.

From the Wikipedia article for [synaptosome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptosome):

> In a collaborative study with the electron microscopist George Gray from University College London, Victor P. Whittaker eventually showed that the acetylcholine-rich particles derived from guinea-pig cerebral cortex were synaptic vesicle-rich pinched-off nerve terminals.  Whittaker coined the term synaptosome to describe these fractionation-derived particles and shortly thereafter synaptic vesicles could be isolated from lysed synaptosomes

Comment: Might be worth putting in his full name in there, Edward George Gray

Comment: @Amory Good idea

Comment: @Amory made the edit.